# apply ffmpeg to many files

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I have written simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -name "*.m4a" | while read filename;
do
    new_filename=$(echo "$filename" | sed "s/^\(.*\)m4a$/\1flac/g");
    if [ ! -f "$new_filename" ]
    then
            #ffmpeg -i "$filename" -acodec flac "$new_filename" > /dev/null 2>&1;
            #wait $!;
            echo "$filename";
            echo "$new_filename";
    fi
done
```

it outputs correct result:

```
./Equilibrium, ALAC [GER] viking.folk/2003 - Demo 2003, ALAC/04 - Met.m4a
./Equilibrium, ALAC [GER] viking.folk/2003 - Demo 2003, ALAC/04 - Met.flac
./Equilibrium, ALAC [GER] viking.folk/2003 - Demo 2003, ALAC/02 - Nach Dem Winter.m4a
./Equilibrium, ALAC [GER] viking.folk/2003 - Demo 2003, ALAC/02 - Nach Dem Winter.flac
```

if uncomment ffmpeg and wait:

```
./Equilibrium, ALAC [GER] viking.folk/2003 - Demo 2003, ALAC/04 - Met.m4a
./Equilibrium, ALAC [GER] viking.folk/2003 - Demo 2003, ALAC/04 - Met.flac
uilibrium, ALAC [GER] viking.folk/2003 - Demo 2003, ALAC/02 - Nach Dem Winter.m4a
uilibrium, ALAC [GER] viking.folk/2003 - Demo 2003, ALAC/02 - Nach Dem Winter.flac
```

And no flacs has been done!

PS

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -name "*.m4a" | while read filename;
do
    new_filename=$(echo "$filename" | sed "s/^\(.*\)m4a$/\1flac/g");
    if [ ! -f "$new_filename" ]
    then
            ffmpeg -i "$filename" -acodec flac "$new_filename";
            echo "$filename";
            echo "$new_filename";
    fi
    sleep 5;
done
```

1) encode start but suddenly stop with no error messages

2) encode couldn't start because of "uilibrium" instead of "./Equilibrium"

3) = 1)

4) = 2)

...

last) correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

suddenly found a solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -name "*.m4a" | while read filename;
do
        new_filename=$(echo "$filename" | sed "s/^\(.*\)m4a$/\1flac/g");
        if [ ! -f "$new_filename" ]
        then
                ffmpeg -i "$filename" -acodec flac "$new_filename" &
                wait $!;
        fi
done
```

I don't know why, but if start process in background (&) and than wait for it (wait $!) all works correctly!

Comment: It works because `wait` command waits for previous background process to finish first which is captured by `$!`

Comment: on Apple Silicon M1 or later you can run it in parallel without `wait $!` with the use of GPU, it is fast and quiet. To use GPU for video encoding I use `-c:v h264_videotoolbox`. This is where I really feel the power of M1.

Answer (score 1):

Might I suggest that you can provide the following param to ffmpeg. It will process only the current file before moving onto the next file.

ffmpeg's -nostdin option avoids attempting to read user input from stdin otherwise the video file itself is interpreted.

```
ffmpeg -i <filename> ... -nostdin
```

The best part about using the above is that you can continue to use verbosity:

```
ffmpeg -i <filename> ... -nostdin -loglevel panic
```

OR if you would rather report the output to a file do so this way:

```
# Custom log name (optional)
# FFREPORT=./${filename}-$(date +%h.%m.%s).log
ffmpeg -i <filename> ... -nostdin -report
```

You can also use a combination of the two as well.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems I can see:

```
ffmpeg -i "$filename" -acodec flac "$new_filename" > /dev/null 2>&1;
```

Could be printing an error message that you can't see because you're doing `> /dev/null 2>&1`, which will silence any errors.

And

```
wait $!
```

won't do anything useful, because `$!` is only defined if you ran a command in the background (i.e. something with `&`).

Comment: of cource at first there is no /dev/null and wait. but with /dev/null you can concentrate at very strange output

Comment: Well, after that, maybe file names have weird characters.  Try using `find ... -print0 | while read -r -d $'\0'; do..`.

Comment: I have applied this hack but at all nothing happends... suddenly I have found a solution!

Answer (score 0):

Oh, euh, just please simplify your sed, it won't correct your bug, but will be more readeable :-P

```
$ echo m4a.m4a | sed 's/m4a$/flac/g'
m4a.flac
```