# Bash while loop wait until task has completed

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, while-loop

I have a bash script that I created to process videos from within a folder and it's subfolders:

```
find . -type f -name '*.mkv' | while read file;
do
  ffmpeg -i $file ...
done
```

The problem: Instead of the while loop waiting ffmpeg to complete, it continues iterate through the loop. The end result is, files not getting processed. I need a way to have the current while loop iteration to wait until ffmpeg is complete before continuing to the next. Or alternatively a way to queue these items.

Edit: So The solution when iterating over a set of files is to pass the -nostdin param to ffmpeg. Hope this helps anyone else who might have a similar issue.

Also file --> $file was a copy/paste typo.

Comment: Maybe stick the process in the background using the `&` at the end of the `ffmpeg` command?

Comment: What you have should wait for ffmpeg to finish. Are you sure you're not getting an error from ffmpeg (like invalid parameters)?

Comment: The loop as you have it should wait until each of the inner commands runs, unless you have put an `&` at the end of the line.  Do you get any error messages?  Try prefacing the inner command with "echo" and adding a sleep 1 after it, to verify that the loop itself doesn't have issues.  For example, in the command line you give, you're using `file` instead of `$file`

Comment: Does adding `-nostdin` option to `ffmpeg` help? It might be reading all the rest of the input to the while-loop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I realize I posted this a while ago but I found the solution. Thanks for all of the responses. Providing the -nostdin param to ffmpeg will do the trick. It will process only the current file before moving onto the next file for processing.

ffmpeg's -nostdin option avoids attempting to read user input from stdin otherwise the video file itself is interpreted.

```
ffmpeg -i <filename> ... -nostdin
```

The best part about using the above is that you can continue to use verbosity in case an error is thrown in the output:

```
ffmpeg -i <filename> ... -nostdin -loglevel panic
```

OR if you would rather report the output to a file do so this way:

```
# Custom log name (optional). Helpful when multiple files are involved.
# FFREPORT=./${filename}-$(date +%h.%m.%s).log
ffmpeg -i <filename> ... -nostdin -report
```

You can also use a combination of the two as well. Also thanks @Barmar for the solution!

Answer (score 3):

I think that this is as simple as you missing the `$` before `file`.

```
find . -type f -name '*.mkv' | while read file;
do
    ffmpeg -i $file ...
done
```

Answer (score 3):

This is good for you?

```
find . -type f -name '*.mkv' -exec ffmpeg -i {} \;
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm a vicious answer snatcher. I found one:

```
ffmpeg -i $file &
wait $!
```

Thanks to puchu, here: [apply ffmpeg to many files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244279/apply-ffmpeg-to-many-files)

Comment: This is an interesting approach I'll have to try this. Thanks! I found that providing the ffmpeg param -nostdin did the trick.