# ffmpeg in bash only works on every second file

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, mono

---

EDIT:

The Solution is to change the original ffmpeg-call below to the following:
`ffmpeg -nostdin -loglevel 16 -i "$dir/$var" -map_channel 0.0.0 "$left" -map_channel 0.0.1 "$right"`
where the `-nostdin` is the crucial thing.
For reference see [apply ffmpeg to many files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244279/apply-ffmpeg-to-many-files?rq=1) (comment by macmichael01)

---

I'm trying to convert all .wav-files in a given directory and it's subdirectorys into two mono-files each with the following bash script. The crucial part is almost at the bottom - the ffmpeg call:

```
#!/bin/bash
# "[One] Stereo [file] to two mono [files] - stereo22mono"

# Syntax ffmpeg siehe: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation


ls -R $1 > .s22mtmp.txt

while read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do

    var=$line
    tst=$var
    tst="${tst%:}"

    if [ -d "${tst%./}" ]       # is directory name
    then
        dir=$tst

    elif [ -f "$dir/$var" ]     # is file name
    then
        left=$dir/left_$var
        right=$dir/right_$var

        #loglevel 16 = only errors
        # -i ...-> input file
        # ffmpeg ... [SOURCE] ... [TARGET1] ... [TARGET2]
        ffmpeg -loglevel 16 -i "$dir/$var" -map_channel 0.0.0 "$left" -map_channel 0.0.1 "$right"
    fi

done < .s22mtmp.txt


rm .s22mtmp.txt
```

It almost works - besides the fact, that it only does it's job on only every second file, although the for-loop correctly goes through all files (watched it with echo) and calls ffmpeg.
I thought it might be that ffmpeg has not finished it's assigned work by the time it is asked to work on the next file and therefore just refuses, which seems to be true.
Because I made one try with disowning every call of ffmpeg like so:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel 16 -i "$dir/$var" -map_channel 0.0.0 "$left" -map_channel 0.0.1 "$right" & disown
```

This worked almost, the problem was just that kind of hundreds of processes and multiple times more threads where starting to run and wouldn't complete in a reasonable time, so I arborted. :D
But at least it didn't skip every second file anymore with that kind of call.

Can anyone give me a hint, how to get this done? Would be very thankful.. it's actually the first time I'm trying with bash scripts.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't need a temp file.  It would be cleaner to just pipe the `ls` output directly into the `while` command.

Comment: And it would be even cleaner to avoid parsing `ls`'s output and use globbing instead : `shopt -s globstar; for wavFile in **/*.wav; do ... done` shoud do the trick without having to handle directories. `globstar` requires bash > 4.0

Comment: @JohnBollinger @Aaron Thank both of you, sadly I wasen't able to implment either of your suggestions, only got erros >_< Do you know a good introduction or reference page for bash, just like cplusplus.com for c++?
Besides that I guess this still wouldn't solve the main problem, but "just" make the code shorter and more efficient.
I also found `ffmpeg -i "$filename" -acodec flac "$new_filename" &; wait $!;` which solved a similar problem for someone else - in my case it's still skipping every second file even with that...

Comment: @kay [The Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) is uncommonly easy to read for a software manual.  Not necessarily easy in an absolute sense, I suppose, but it's worth a look.

Comment: Well, I finally found the solution for it in [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244279/apply-ffmpeg-to-many-files?rq=1] in a reply by @macmichael01:
Just had to add the option `-no-stdin` to the ffmpeg call. I will modify the initial post according to this.
@John Bollinger thank you, I'll give it a try! At least it's a very neat plain text webpage ;)